# Add support for negative numbers in D3.js bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following code for generating a bar chart using d3.js, while this graph works it does not support negative numbers.

I'm wanting the traditional bar chart where the x-axis is inline with the 0 on the y-axis and the negative numbers are facing the opposite way to the positive ones.

I have tried the following:

```
 y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([Math.min(0, min), Math.max(0, max)])
        .range([height, 0]);
```

While this does show the negative numbers, it does not look correct as the x-axis is not at y = 0 and the negative bars are facing the same direction as positive bars.

My code :

```js
  let payloadResponse = {
    "text": "",
    "chart": "bar",
    "dims": [{
      "dim0": "Year Month"
    }],
    "metrics": [{
      "metric0": "Rev"
    }],
    "totals": [{
      "metric0": "0",
    }],
    "data": [{
      "dim0": "2022-09",
      "metric0": "159487698",
    }, {
      "dim0": "2022-10",
      "metric0": "68008958",
    }, {
      "dim0": "2022-11",
      "metric0": "16152370",
    }, {
      "dim0": "2022-12",
      "metric0": "-9865752",
    }, {
      "dim0": "2023-01",
      "metric0": "46135223",
    }, {
      "dim0": "2023-02",
      "metric0": "11003565",
    }, {
      "dim0": "2023-03",
      "metric0": "-31017278",
    }, {
      "dim0": "2023-04",
      "metric0": "-37912892",
    }, {
      "dim0": "2023-05",
      "metric0": "96426636",
    }, {
      "dim0": "2023-06",
      "metric0": "-34053237",
    }, {
      "dim0": "2023-07",
      "metric0": "-32393213",
    }, {
      "dim0": "2023-08",
      "metric0": "24596177",
    }]
  }
  
    let options = {};
  let barWidth;
  let labelLengths = [];

  const response = _.cloneDeep(payloadResponse);
  const d3ChartData = [];
  const horizontal = false
  
  
  //console.log("response","",response)

  response.data.forEach(m => {
    m.metric0 = parseFloat(m.metric0);
  });


  const total = _.sumBy(response.data, 'metric0')
  const { percentValues } = options;

  //console.log("percentValues","",percentValues)
  
  const metrics = [];
  response.metrics.forEach(m => {
    metrics.push({ key: Object.keys(m)[0], name: Object.values(m)[0] });
  });
  //console.log("metrics","",metrics)
  
    const dimensions = [];
  response.dims.forEach(d => {
    dimensions.push({ key: Object.keys(d)[0], name: Object.values(d)[0] });
  });
  //console.log("dimensions","",dimensions)
  
    response.data.forEach(row => {
    const newobject = {};
    newobject["category"] = row[dimensions[0].key];
    newobject["values"] = row[metrics[0].key];//Y axis metrics
    metrics.forEach((s, i) => {
      row[metrics[i].key] = percentValues ? percentage(row[metrics[i].key] / total) : row[metrics[i].key]
      newobject[s.name] = row[metrics[i].key]
    })
    d3ChartData.push(newobject)
  })
  
  
  const groups = d3.map(d3ChartData, function (d) { return d["category"] }).keys();
  const valueGroups = d3.map(d3ChartData, function (d) { return d["values"] }).keys();//Y axis group
  subgroups = d3.map(metrics, function (d) { return d["name"] }).keys();
  subgroups = _.sortBy(subgroups);

  const newdataset = d3ChartData;
  
  
  
    const minarray = [];
  metrics.forEach((s, i) => {
    minarray.push((Math.min.apply(Math, response.data.map(function (o) {
      return Math.round(o[metrics[i].key]);
    }))))
  })

  let min = Math.min.apply(Math, minarray)

  const maxarray = [];
  metrics.forEach((s, i) => {
    maxarray.push((Math.max.apply(Math, response.data.map(function (o) {
      return Math.round(o[metrics[i].key]);
    }))))
  })
  
  
  let max = Math.max.apply(Math, maxarray)
  max = max * 1.1;


  let longestLabel = Math.max.apply(Math, maxarray).toString().length;
  if(longestLabel < 5)
    {
      longestLabel = 5;
    }
    
    
//START spacing for axis tick labels
let chartBottom = Math.max(...(groups.map(el => el.length)));

let longestValue = Math.max(...(valueGroups.map(el => Math.trunc(el).toString().length)));

let ySpacing = longestValue*10 >= 60 ? longestValue*10 == 70 ? longestValue*( (10 + Math.ceil(longestValue/3))+3) : longestValue*( (10 + Math.ceil(longestValue/3) )) : 80;


let margin = { top: 10, right: 20, bottom: horizontal ? ySpacing<150 ? ySpacing : 130 : chartBottom < 14 ? 100 : (chartBottom * 8), left: !horizontal ? ySpacing  : chartBottom < 14 ? 100 : (chartBottom * 8)},
width = 340,
height = 310;
   
   
        
        
var svg = d3.select("#chart")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
      

    
let sizeDimensions = {
    margin: margin,
    height: height,
    width: width
  }

let x, y;



if(!horizontal){
    
  //Original 
  x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(groups)
    .range([0, width])
    .padding([0.2]) 
       

    // Add Y axis
y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, max])
    .range([height, 0]);
    
/*         y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([Math.min(0, min), Math.max(0, max)])
            .range([height, 0]); */

let makeYLines = () => d3.axisRight()
    .scale(y);
svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${width}, 0)`)
    .attr("class", "gridlines")
    .call(makeYLines().tickSize(-width, 0, 0).tickFormat(''));
  }
  
  
  
  else
  {
    // Add y axis
 y = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(groups)
    .range([0, height])
    .padding([0.2])

 // Add x axis
 x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, max])
    .range([0, width]);

 let makeXLines = () => d3.axisBottom().scale(x)
 svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height} )`)
    .attr("class", "gridlines")
    .call(makeXLines().tickSize(-height).tickFormat(''));
  }
  
  
  
svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSizeOuter(0))
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("class", "axis-text")
    //.attr("transform", function (d) {return !horizontal ? "rotate(0)" : "rotate(-30)"})
    .attr("text-anchor", "end");

  // Another scale for subgroup position?
let xSubgroup = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(subgroups)
    .range([0, (!horizontal ? x.bandwidth() : y.bandwidth())])
    .padding([0.05])

  // color palette = one color per subgroup
let color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(subgroups)
    .range(['green', 'pink'])


    
//adds bars  
svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
    // Enter in data = loop group per group
  .data(newdataset)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function (d) {return !horizontal ? ("translate(" + x(d.category) + ",0)") : ("translate(0," + y(d.category) + ")");})
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function (d){return subgroups.map(function (key) {return { key: key, value: d[key], category: d.category };});})
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr(!horizontal ? "x" : "y", function (d) {return xSubgroup(d.key);})
  .attr(!horizontal ? "y" : "x", function (d) {return !horizontal ? y(0) : x(0);})
  .attr(!horizontal ? "width" : "height", xSubgroup.bandwidth())
  .attr(!horizontal ? "height" : "width", function (d) {return !horizontal ? (height - y(0)) : (x(0));})
  .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.key); })
    

    
 
    
svg.selectAll('rect') // select all the text elements 
  .each(function(d){ barWidth = this.getBBox().width})

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))
  .selectAll("text")
  .each(function(d){ labelLengths.push(this.getBBox().width)})
  .attr("transform", function (d) {return horizontal ? percentValues ? "rotate(0)" : longestValue < 2 ? "rotate(0)" : "rotate(270)" : barWidth>Math.max(...labelLengths) ? "rotate(0)" : "rotate(270)"})
  .attr("y", function (d) {return horizontal ? percentValues ? 8 : longestValue < 2 ? 8 : -4 : barWidth>Math.max(...labelLengths) ? 8 : -4})
  .attr("x", function (d) {return horizontal ? percentValues ? 0 : longestValue < 2 ? 0 : -7 : barWidth>Math.max(...labelLengths) ? 0 : -7})
  .attr("class", "axis-text x-axis-text")
  .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {return horizontal ? percentValues ? "middle" : longestValue < 2 ? "middle" : "end" : barWidth>Math.max(...labelLengths) ? "middle" : "end"});


  // Animation
  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .ease(d3.easePoly)
    .attr(!horizontal ? "y" : "x", function (d) {
      return !horizontal ? y(d.value) : x(0);
    })
    .attr(!horizontal ? "height" : "width", function (d) {
      return !horizontal ? (height - y(d.value)) : (x(d.value))
    })
    .delay(function (d, i) { return (i * 30) })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

<script src="lodash.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="500" id="chart"></svg>
```

Thank you for any help in advance!